# Error:SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J

Tags: pyspark

While running the PYSPARK code, I am getting

```py
> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
> binding in
> [jar:file:/C:/work/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> SLF4J: Found binding in
> [jar:file:/C:/work/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> SLF4J:

 See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

Answer (score 0):

**By removing** "slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!" JAR file from this path  C:/work/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!

And **kept** "slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar" in this path C:/work/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar

Issue Resolved!!!!!!!!!!